# Exim as relay server

Tags: email, smtp, exim

Hi I have exim running on port 8900 and another mail server running on port 25. This mail server will be used to relay outgoing emails to exim. But somehow I am getting this error from exim `550, 'relay not permitted'` when relaying email to exim. Is there any way I can configure exim to permit relaying?

All iedas are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your config:

```
hostlist   relay_from_hosts = 127.0.0.1 : 10.0.0.1/24
```

This will allow relaying from `localhost` and `10.0.0.1/24`. Change `10.0.0.1/24` to whatever host/mask combination suits your network.

Comment: Is `10.0.0.1/24` the local interface ip?

Comment: The list following the equals sign is a colon-delimited list of networks (in CIDR notation) that you want to allow relaying from.