# how to prevent open relay with exim

Tags: exim

I have [setup exim as a relay server running on nonstandard port](https://serverfault.com/questions/191634/exim-as-relay-server). But now spammers have abused it as a relay server for them. How do I prevent this from happening? Can I still have my server as a relay server but prevent spammers to abuse it at the same time?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend requiring authentication.  [This document](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-3.30/doc/html/spec_35.html) and [this wiki entry](http://wiki.exim.org/Authentication) on authentication should help (I've never used Exim so I can't help with the detail I'm afraid).